# Why I get status: Unknown job on the service?

Tags: linux, services

I followed [this](https://cakecreeper.wordpress.com/2014/05/21/noip-com-dynamic-dns-update-client-app-install-on-ubuntu-linux-start-up-script-how-to-uninstall/) tutorial to add a program to init.d as a service (I guess), when I want to see its status with:

```
sudo status /etc/init.d/noip2
```

I get :

```
status: Unknown job: /etc/init.d/noip2
```

What it mean? should I change the program?

Program is:

```sh
#! /bin/sh

# /etc/init.d/noip2
# Supplied by no-ip.com
# Modified for Debian GNU/Linux by Eivind L. Rygge <eivind@rygge.org>
# Updated by David Courtney to not use pidfile 130130 for Debian stable.

# . /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions  # uncomment/modify for your killproc

DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/noip2
NAME=noip2

test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

case "$1" in
   start)
       echo -n "Starting dynamic address update: "
       start-stop-daemon –start –exec $DAEMON
       echo "noip2."
   ;;

   stop)
       echo -n "Shutting down dynamic address update:"
       start-stop-daemon –stop –oknodo –retry 30 –exec $DAEMON
       echo "noip2."
   ;;

   restart)
       echo -n "Restarting dynamic address update: "
       start-stop-daemon –stop –oknodo –retry 30 –exec $DAEMON
       start-stop-daemon –start –exec $DAEMON
       echo "noip2."
   ;;

   *)
       echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
       exit 1
   ;;

esac
exit 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is an `init.d` script.  The `status` command is for Upstart jobs; not for `init.d` scripts.

`initctl list` is used to list all Upstart jobs.  If you try it, you'll find that `noip2` isn't there.  In fact, you'll find that none of the scripts from `/etc/init.d` are shown by that command. `initctl list` (and the `status` command you tried), works with the Upstart configuration files from `/etc/init` (note the lack of `.d`) only.

The command to check the status of a script from `/etc/init.d` is usually:

```
# service <script> status
```

However, for that to work, the script must support a `status` function, which yours doesn't.

Your script has three options: `start`, `stop` and `restart` which means that these are the only three commands you can pass to `service noip2 <cmd>`.  If you read others within `/etc/init.d` you'll find that they have more options, such as `status`.

In fact, if you read the article in the link you posted, you'll see that the way to check the status of `noip2` is:

```
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/noip2 –S
```

Comment: i don't understand,it's process user is "nobody" and there is no other way to stop it beside killing it's process.

Comment: `service noip2 stop`.